# Unauthorized operation while reading elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have some resources deployed onto AWS, but while I try to remove them, I am receiving an unauthorized error.

The action the operation requires is an EC2:DescribeAddresses for the elasticIP resource. I tried using a complete wild card (`Resource: "*"`) to see if there was any issue with the resources I was defining, but that didn't work. Below is the error:

`Error: reading EC2 EIP (eipalloc-xxxx): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

Below is my IAM policy attached to the role my terraform script is assuming:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AssociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeNatGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:route-table/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:vpn-gateway/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:ipam-pool/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:natgateway/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:vpc/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:ipv6pool-ec2/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:internet-gateway/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2ElasticIPWildcard",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses" //Action that allows it to read the elastic IP
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:elastic-ip/*" //Also tried a complete wildcard, but di not work
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Cognito",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPool"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you might need `ec2:DescribeInstances` as well.

Comment: What is the command you ran when the error appeared?